# C - Execl system call

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm trying to execute a function using execl on a child process and it is returning an error.
Here is my code for it:

```
pid_t Process = fork();
if(Process == 0){
    execl("path/to/executable/executable", "executable", "function", "function_parameter", (const char*)NULL);
}
else if(Process < 0){ //do something
}
else
{
   //parent 
}
```

The program reads commands from the stdin (each command is a function) and 'function name' and 'function parameter' are inputs.  For
example:

```
$ ./executable

Welcome to the program

functionN 2

(function N gets executed with 2 as a parameter)
$
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Check whether the `execl` call succeeded or not (if it returns then it failed). And "The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed".

Comment: @kaylum It does not return -1, that means it succeeded right? I've noticed it enters the program as it prints "Welcome to the program" but it does not run arg0 and arg1...

Comment: Well, that's a different problem then. You said "nothing happens"! That's very misleading as you are now saying the executable was actually run. We can't see the code for the program being called . But as I said, most programs expect arg0 to be the program name and if that is the case then all your args are out of place.

Comment: Note that if you'd run `executable arg0 arg1` at the command line, you need to use `execl("path/to/executable", "executable", "arg0", "arg1", (char *)NULL);`.  You should also do something sane (meaning, 'report an error and exit with an error status') if `execl()` returns, which it will if it fails to execute the command.  On success, it does not return.  There's no need, therefore, to test the return value from `execl()`.

Comment: @kaylum Okay so I've used that "path-to-file", "file" convention and now it returns so it is returning an error

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is my code: execl("path/to/executable", "executable", "function", "function_parameter", (const char*)NULL);

Comment: Please click the "edit" link under the question to fix up the obvious misleading statements and also to add any updated code that you try. We cannot debug descriptions of code. The *exact* code must be shown (in the question not in comments).

Comment: OK; are you typing two values on the standard input, or are you passing two arguments on the command line?  Do you run `executable arg0 arg1` or do you run `executable` and then specify `arg0` and `arg1` as commands typed on standard input?  If the latter, you have some work to do — you have to create a file or pipe for the program to read from, and write the two values to that file or pipe, and redirect input so the child process reads from the file or pipe.

Comment: Call `perror` after the `execl` returns to get a more precise error description.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thats exactly what I want. should i use an echo to write on a .txt file? How can i make the program read that file afterwards using execl? execl("path/to/executable", "executable < inputFile",  (const char*)NULL); will this work?

Comment: @kaylum sorry, not only english is not my first language but also the code variables and files are not in english... doing my best to be clear

Comment: The easiest fix would be to make `executable` look at whether it is given command line arguments and to use them if it is and to prompt for the data only if there were no command line arguments. Assuming that this change is not admissible, you need to look up [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) in particular, and maybe [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), etc. You can't do the I/O redirection as you commented; that requires the shell to interpret the `<`, using `system("path/to/executable < inputFile")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the input to the standard input of the executable, so you should probably use a pipe:

```
int p[2];
pipe(p);      // Error check?

pid_t Process = fork();
if (Process < 0)
{
    perror("fork()");
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
}
else if (Process == 0)
{
    dup2(p[0], 0);
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    execl("path/to/executable/executable", "executable", (char *)NULL);
    perror("executable");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    close(p[0]);
    write(p[1], "functionN 2\n", sizeof("functionN 2\n")-1);
    close(p[1]);
    int status;
    pid_t corpse = wait(&status);
}
```

For the code shown, you need headers `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/wait.h>` (in addition to `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`).  There are a myriad other ways to get the line `functionN 2` specified; it would be more orthodox, perhaps, to use:

```
char line[] = "functionN 2\n";
…
write(p[1], line, sizeof(line) - 1);
```

(Remember that `sizeof()` includes the terminal null in a string literal, or when sizing a string array like `line`; that should not be written to the child.)

You should, arguably, check that the `corpse` value matches the `Process` value.  You would loop until you either get the correct corpse or you get an error indicating no more children.  This protects you if you have other processes also started by the parent that have not yet been waited for.  You should also consider reporting the corpse and its exit status, at least for debugging purposes:

```
int status = 0;
pid_t corpse;

while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != Process && corpse != -1)
    printf("Other child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)corpse, status);
if (corpse == -1)
    printf("Oops! Executable died and we did not get told!\n");
else
    printf("Executable %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)corpse, status);
```